# Click recyclerView new activity Error Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need help , for onclick on recyclerview and open new actity, im clicked in item list close app and logcat error is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

My code :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final estadoView estadoView, final int i) {
    final Estado estado = estadoList.get(i);
    estadoView.txtnombreMostrar.setText(estado.getStateName());



   estadoView.txtnombreMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent =  new Intent(context, Invernadero.class);
           context.startActivity(intent);
       } });


}
```

And my public class is:

```
public class estadoView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView  txtnombreMostrar;

    RelativeLayout parentLayout;


    public estadoView(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    txtnombreMostrar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreMostrar);

    }

}
```

whats is the problem? Im search in web , in forums , but im not solve my problem

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlNcX.png)
[image]

[LogCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzcpl.png)
[image]

[context is null, how to solved?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bhdQ.png)
[image]

Comment: Can you share your items.xml here?

Comment: its look like you are referencing wrong view in the code, it will be help full you match your xml ids with java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've a context issue, but as you didn't provide how did you get the context, for now replace it in your view listener with `v.getContext()` as below:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final estadoView estadoView, final int i) {
    final Estado estado = estadoList.get(i);
    estadoView.txtnombreMostrar.setText(estado.getStateName());



   estadoView.txtnombreMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent =  new Intent(v.getContext(), Invernadero.class);
           v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
       } });


}
```

Comment: @ManzoorAhmad yeah both should work .. v is the same view as estadoView .. as View is the parent class

Comment: Zain, hi how are you, i need help please in ths post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618675/android-retrofit-json-insert-in-sqlite

Comment: Hi Zain, sorry for bothering you, can you help me with this question, about how to get mparent data from a textview

Comment: Hi @MexiCano which question please

Comment: Hi Zain, help me please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811228/refresh-oncreateview-fragment

Comment: @MexiCano sure please let me check as i can't write answer right now

Comment: Thanks Zain, i wait for you helped, and continue search solution, in what you answer

Answer (score 0):

check your context when start a new Intent, where you get the context, maybe the context still null or not assigned yet

`java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()`

i'm sure the context is null

Comment: you can use the view that triggering click like @zain said above